# How to add text extracted by OCR to the pypdf PageObject?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, ocr, pypdf

I am trying to add the text I extracted via OCR to the [pypdf PageObject](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/PageObject.html) and save/overwrite the pdf with its OCR'd text, so I only have to run OCR once and fall back to the already OCR'd text while handling the file somewhere else.

So here is what I am doing right now:

```
pdf_file = PdfReader(pdf_path)
# check if text is available or if the pdf needs ocr
for page in pdf_file.pages:
    text = page.extract_text() # default pypdf method to get text, if there is any
    if not text:
        text = ""
        # get all images from the page to OCR the text
        images = page.images
        for image_raw in images:
            # this method just returns a string of the OCR'd text
            text += extract_text_from_image(image_raw)
```

So is there a method to add this text back to the PageObject or do I have to take a different approach? Any tips are appreciated, maybe I just need another hint on how to approach this (smarter).

Comment: If you are interested, there is an easy solution using PyMuPDF.

Comment: @JorjMcKie thanks, that might be my fallback solution, but I hoped with pypdf's PdfWriter it would be easier to do without using another package.